# Interposing on Java Class Methods (without interfaces)

Tags: java, reflection, interposing

I'd like to interpose between class methods to dynamically extends an object.

I already know about the java.lang.reflect.Proxy stuff, but it's way too limited to do real interposing.

From [Using java.lang.reflect.Proxy to Interpose on Java Class Methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626005343/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/Interposing), the first limitation is :

> (...) the method must be called through an instance of the proxy class. So nested methods calls, for instance, would not be intercepted.

And the worst one :

> (...) the method must have been defined in an Interface that is implemented by the object being proxied. It can not be called through an instance of a class that does not implement an interface.

The object I'd like to extends at run-time doesn't implement any interface, and worst, the methods I need to override are nested and private.

I know this is fairly easy in Python & C, and the article cited above says that it could be possible :

> The next article in this series will illustrate some techniques for overcoming these limitations.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find this article.

Comment: That article is from 2001. It's *11 years old*. You may want to try and find something less prehistoric to base your experiments on.

Comment: This sort of changes are usually considered very bad programming practices.  It can lead to unmaintainable and unsupportable code.  What you suggest usually has a better way of being done. I suspect you have a particular solution to a problem in mind. Would you consider other solutions to the same problem?

Comment: Sometimes, hacking is the only way to do it. If you're interested in the (long) story, send me a PM =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using CGLIB:

Here is a tutorial I wrote a couple of years ago, its quite simple introduction to CGLIB: [CGLIB intro](http://markbramnik.blogspot.com/2010/04/cglib-introduction.html)

If you need even more power, consider to use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)

Hope this helps

Comment: I forget to precise it was related to Android. Is AspectJ compatible with Android ?